# Django registration redux registration only with email (no password)

Tags: python, django, django-forms

Is there any way to implement form only with email field (without password and username)? User will receive email with link to confirm his account and set password.

Any information will be helpfull, thanks.

**To user Temka**:

I've already have cutom RegistrationForm:

```
from registration.forms import RegistrationForm


class UserForm(RegistrationForm):
    username = forms.CharField(
        max_length=254,
        required=False,
        widget=forms.HiddenInput(),
    )
    password1 = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.HiddenInput(),
        required=False,
    )

    password2 = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.HiddenInput(),
        required=False,
    )

    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        self.cleaned_data['username'] = email
        return email

    def clean_password2(self):
        pass
```

Also thanks for "unusable password" info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### User model

First you need to create custom User manager and model.
Documentation can be found here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/customizing/#a-full-example

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin, BaseUserManager

class EmailUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, password=None):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')

        user = self.model(email=self.normalize_email(email),)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password):
        user = self.create_user(email, password=password,)
        user.is_admin = True
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user


class EmailUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = EmailField(
        verbose_name='email',
        max_length=255,
        unique=True,
    )
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    objects = EmailUserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'

    def get_full_name(self):
        return self.email

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.email

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        return self.is_admin
```

And register it in your settings.py with this line `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'app.EmailUser'`.
Now your EmailUser model can be used with `from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model` and `from django.conf.settings import AUTH_USER_MODEL`.

Example usage (foreign key):

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf.settings import AUTH_USER_MODEL

class Profile(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Profile'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Profiles'

    user = models.OneToOneField(AUTH_USER_MODEL, verbose_name='User',
                                related_name='profile')
    full_name = models.CharField('Full name', max_length=64, blank=False)
    phone = models.CharField('Phone', max_length=64, blank=True)
```

### Registration

When using *django-registration-redux* two-step registration:

- Create `User` with None password on registration. This will make User model with unusable password https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.has_usable_password. It may be necessary to create custom `RegistrationForm` and `RegistrationView` to avoid password checking.
- On activation form submit (activation form template with password field) use methods `RegistrationManager.activate_user(key)` and `User.set_password(password)`